# How to call funcions with basic authentication enabled in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, flask-restful

I am using basic authentication with the decorator in a flask application.
The code looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('settings')

def valid_credentials(username, password):
    return username == app.config['USER'] and password == app.config['PASS']

def authenticate(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        if not auth.username or not auth.password or not valid_credentials(auth.username, auth.password):
            return Response('Login!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login!"'})
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

@app.route('/secure')
@authenticate
def secure():
    return 'Secure!'

@app.route('/check')
@authenticate
def check():
    secure()
    return 'checked'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I am not able to call the secure function from check function due to the authentication. Now is it possible to call the function in the current scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is to keep helper methods separate from views. For example:

```
def _secure():
    return 'Secure!'

@app.route('/secure')
@authenticate
def secure():
    return _secure()
```

You can then reuse the helper method (`_secure()`) from other places. Since it doesn't have a route associated it is not possible for a visitor to run it without authentication.

It is also a good idea to keep these helper methods in a separate module (such as `helpers.py` or `utils.py`).

Comment: I got it, we can do it separating the method from the route, but is it really possible to do it with route attached to it? Earlier I thought, the decorators only work when the routes are called, not the function. Looks like I was completely wrong. Any clear explanation?

Comment: Decorators are simply syntactic sugar for wrapping a function into another, so yes, they are used no matter where you use it from.